# Dynamically change caption field (or just title in tabs macro) in TiddlyWiki

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I'm putting together some TiddlyWiki templates, and I've run into something that would be nice to have, but I'm not sure whether it's actually possible.

I have some tiddlers that I'm including in another tiddler using the `tabs` macro. Each tiddler has one of two tags associated with it. I'd like to append a snippet of text to the `caption` in the tab view, based on which tag is associated.

I don't have a strong preference for whether this is done by adding some kind of callback to edit the `caption` on save, something that somehow calculates the desired `caption` on the fly, altering the invocation of the `tabs` macro to recalculate the `caption` on render, or somehow causing the templates to calculate the `caption` field.

I haven't found anything promising going through the documentation, but maybe I just haven't figured out what's relevant to my issue. I find that happens a lot.

Like, I'm sure I can write conditionals based on whether the tags exist, but I can't see any way to interpolate text into the `caption` field based on any kind of computation whatsoever.

For reference, here are my current macro invocations:

```
<<tabs [list[]] state:$:/state/tabPeriod template:PeriodTemplate>>

<<tabs [list[$(currentTab)$]] state:$:/state/tabEvent class:"tc-vertical" template:"EventTemplate">>

<<tabs [list[$(currentTab)$]] state:$:/state/tabScene template:"SceneTemplate">>
```

All of these lines are from different templates, that just pull a list of tiddlers and template-transclude them into tabs using the provided template. *Currently*, the tabs are captioned with the tiddler `caption`, if defined, and fall back to the `title`. I'd like to alter the caption, ideally without inserting too much boilerplate into the tiddlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I need to do differently: I defined a custom macro based on the tabs macro, added the logic, and now it works fine. I basically just changed the current contents of the caption logic to:

```
<$set name="tv-wikilinks" value="no">
<$transclude tiddler=<<currentTab>> field="caption">
<$macrocall $name="currentTab" $type="text/plain" $output="text/plain"/>
</$transclude>
<$list filter='[<currentTab>tag[light]]'>
○
</$list>
<$list filter='[<currentTab>tag[dark]]'>
●
</$list>
</$set>
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the list widget correctly, but it works.